# How to Have Multiple Softmax Outputs in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to create a network in tensor flow with multiple softmax outputs, each of a different size. The network architecture is:
Input -> LSTM -> Dropout. Then I have 2 softmax layers: Softmax of 10 outputs and Softmax of 20 Outputs. The reason for this is because I want to generate two sets of outputs (10 and 20), and then combine them to produce a final output. I'm not sure how to do this in Tensorflow.

Previously, to make a network like described, but with one softmax, I think I can do something like this.

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, maxlength, vocabsize])
lengths = tf.placeholders(tf.int32, [batch_size])
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabsize, 256], -1, 1))
lstm = {}
lstm[0] = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_layer_size, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=random_seed))
lstm[0] = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm[0], output_keep_prob=0.5)
lstm[0] = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=[lstm[0]] * 1, state_is_tuple=True)
output_layer = {}
output_layer[0] = Layer.W(1 * hidden_layer_size, 20, 'OutputLayer')
output_bias = {}
output_bias[0] = Layer.b(20, 'OutputBias')
outputs = {}
fstate = {}
with tf.variable_scope("lstm0"):
    # create the rnn graph at run time
  outputs[0], fstate[0] = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm[0], tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, inputs),
                                      sequence_length=lengths, 
                                      dtype=tf.float32)
logits = {}
logits[0] = tf.matmul(tf.concat([f.h for f in fstate[0]], 1), output_layer[0]) + output_bias[0]
loss = {}
loss[0] = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits[0], labels=labels[0]))
```

However, now, I want my RNN output (after the dropout) to flow into 2 softmax layers, one of size 10 and another of size 20. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Thanks

Edit: Ideally I would like to use a version of softmax such as what is defined here in this Knet Julia library. Does Tensorflow have an equivalent? 
https://github.com/denizyuret/Knet.jl/blob/1ef934cc58f9671f2d85063f88a3d6959a49d088/deprecated/src7/op/actf.jl#L103

Comment: I now have a question with some size problems, see the question I added as a comment to the correctly chosen answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following on the output of `dynamic_rnn` that you called `output[0]` in order to compute the two softmax and the corresponding losses:

```
with tf.variable_scope("softmax_0"):
    # Transform you RNN output to the right output size = 10
    W = tf.get_variable("kernel_0", [output[0].get_shape()[1], 10])
    logits_0 = tf.matmul(inputs, W)
    # Apply the softmax function to the logits (of size 10)
    output_0 = tf.nn.softmax(logits_0, name = "softmax_0")
    # Compute the loss (as you did in your question) with softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits directly applied on logits
    loss_0 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_0, labels=labels[0]))

with tf.variable_scope("softmax_1"):  
    # Transform you RNN output to the right output size = 20
    W = tf.get_variable("kernel_1", [output[0].get_shape()[1], 20])
    logits_1 = tf.matmul(inputs, W)
    # Apply the softmax function to the logits (of size 20)
    output_1 = tf.nn.softmax(logits_1, name = "softmax_1")
    # Compute the loss (as you did in your question) with softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits directly applied on logits
    loss_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_1, labels=labels[1]))
```

You can then combine the two losses if it is relevant to your application:

```
total_loss = loss_0 + loss_1
```

**EDIT**
To answer your question in comment about what you specifically need to do with the two softmax outputs: you can do the following approximately:

```
with tf.variable_scope("second_part"):
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W_1", [output_1.get_shape()[1], n])
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W_2", [output_2.get_shape()[1], n])
    prediction = tf.matmul(output_1, W1) + tf.matmul(output_2, W2)
with tf.variable_scope("optimization_part"):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(prediction, label))
```

You just need to defined `n`, the number of columns of W1 and W2.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What if I wanted to extend this, by multiplying the output of the each softmax by another matrix, then adding the resulting matrices to get my final output, which is also a matrix. I am confused as to how I would handle the loss with respect to that final output. Should I just do my operations on `output_0` and `output_1`, and then add the result? How would I make sure that I am minimizing that loss? In your answer, you are calculating the loss on each softmax with two sets of labels (`labels[0]`, `[labels[1]`), but I only have one output label which is the final result.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a related, but different question now. The RNN cell documentation for Tensorflow says that the input tensor should be one with shape [batch_size x input_size]. However, I have one with size [batch_size x maxlength x features] since I am trying to understand a sentence by passing in words one by one. Maxlength represents the length of the longest sentence. How will this work in this case, right now it throws me an error saying I must have rank 2? Embeddings is a standard matrix of size features x 256. It is before the LSTM. My code is what I have in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't defining your logits for the size 10 softmax layer in your code, and you would have to do that explicitly.

Once that was done, you could use [tf.nn.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax), applying it separately to both of your logit tensors.

For example, for your 20-class softmax tensor:

```
softmax20 = tf.nn.softmax(logits[0])
```

For the other layer, you could do:

```
output_layer[1] = Layer.W(1 * hidden_layer_size, 10, 'OutputLayer10')
output_bias[1] = Layer.b(10, 'OutputBias10')

logits[1] = tf.matmul(tf.concat([f.h for f in fstate[0]], 1), 
output_layer[1]) + output_bias[1]

softmax10 = tf.nn.softmax(logits[1])
```

There is also a [tf.contrib.layers.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/softmax) which allows you to apply the softmax on the final axis of a tensor with greater than 2 dimensions, but it doesn't look like you need anything like that. [tf.nn.softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) should work here.

*Side note:* `output_layer` is not the greatest name for that list - should be something involving weights. These weights and biases (`output_layer`, `output_bias`) also do not represent the output layer of your network (as that will come from whatever you do to your softmax outputs, right?). [Sorry, couldn't help myself.]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am now confused as to how to handle the loss with respect to these softmax results as I am not trying to output these as a result but rather do some operations with them to compute the actual result.  See my comment on the other answer, do you have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: @MehtaiPhoneApps: Can you provide more details about the loss that you would like to use?In general, you would have to represent your loss function using TensorFlow ops, and use an [optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer) to minimize/maximize it.

Comment: Ok, after having the two softmax layers like you have in your answer, I can multiply one of them by a matrix, another by a weight vector using a (W*x) operation, and then I have 2 outputs say `prediction_1` and `prediction_2`. I can add these matrices to get a final output, `prediction`. Then, I would use a loss function on this, like this: ```loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(prediction, label))```. I am curious, would doing this back propagate the gradients correctly, even through the softmax, since I don't use the loss on the softmax directly.

Comment: This would not be a problem for backpropagation, but this way you loose the interest of the softmax because you final output `prediction` is not constrained anymore

Comment: Why would you say I loose the interest of the softmax? The softmax is still predicting 10 and 20 things, right? Just trying to understand.